# MongoDB FilterDefinition and interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a MongoDB collection contains differents entity with same interface `IDocument`.

```
public class BarDocument: IDocument
{
    public string BarField { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to find inside this collection doing something like this:

```
var fooDoc = new FooDocument() { FooField = "test Foo Field" };
var barDoc = new BarDocument() { BarField = "test Bar Field" };
var barDoc1 = new BarDocument() { BarField = "test Bar Field 2" };

await _documentsCollection.InsertManyAsync(new List<IDocument>() { fooDoc, barDoc, barDoc1 });



var filterBar = Builders<BarDocument>.Filter.Where(x => x.BarField.Contains("Bar")) ;

var result = await _documentsCollection.Find(filterBar).ToListAsync();
```

But this `Find` statement ends in a compilation error:

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'MongoDB.Driver.FilterDefinition<WebApi.Models.Entities.Documents.BarDocument>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<WebApi.Models.Entities.Documents.IDocument, bool>>'
```

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_documentsCollection` variable is defined as `ICollection<IDocument>>`, thus you can insert documents that are defined both as `FooDocument` and `BarDocument` and it works - MongoDB knows how to store them in one collection and preserve their original type (`_t` field).

Once they're inserted to the same collection, you're trying to query `ICollection<IDocument>>` using filter that is defined on the derived type, which won't be allowed by the compiler, since `BarField` is unknown to `IDocument`.

What you can do is to define another variable which targers `BarDocument` specifically and then run your query on such collection:

```
var barCollection = database.GetCollection<BarDocument>("yourcol");
var filterBar = Builders<BarDocument>.Filter.
                                     Where(x => x.BarField.Contains("Bar"));

var result = await barCollection.Find(filterBar).ToListAsync();
```

This should work as long as your query returns only instances of `BarDocument` class.

Comment: You've got guy!